# Woocommerce product detail page remove price decimals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing Woocommerce plugin, trying to remove decimals from product variation prices in product detail page.

Ex- if someone select option i want to display the regular and sales prices without decimals and the other locations of site like shop, cart, checkout no need to change.

I found this filter but it change prices of whole site.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```

https://snipboard.io/GXgtUi.jpg

anyone have idea or solution about archive this, Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use `__return_true` then, but provide an actual callback function - that checks if you are on a product detail page first, and then returns true or false based on that.

Comment: I tested that by using is_product() function condition but not worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code snippet into your theme function.php file

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ums_remove_zero_decimals', 10, 5 );
function ums_remove_zero_decimals( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
$product_id = get_the_ID();
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

if( is_single()) {
    if($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
        return (int) round( $price );
    }
    else {
        return ( $formatted_price);
    }
}
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: It seems not working when add it to function.php file the product price gone and shows like this https://snipboard.io/Q0vl4W.jpg

Comment: Did you used any other plugin which alter the price.
What about the price in the Simple product.
Can you tried with deactivating any supporting plugin. I have tried on my local it was working fine

Comment: I think no, the original variable price out put is like this, i think it's original one <div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,798.00</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>628.00</span></ins></span></div>

Comment: Can you replace above condition with below code.
if( is_single()) {
  if($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
   return  $price;
  }
  else {
   return ( $formatted_price);
  }
 }
Let me know the result of Simple product and variable product after replacing with this code.

Comment: Getting same results